# how to install libcontainer docker in place of lxc-docker

Tags: docker

On my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, I ran the following command, to make sure that I'm running the latest docker:

sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh

During the install, I have noticed the following:

Setting up lxc-docker-1.5.0 (1.5.0)...

This leads me to believe that I had lxc-docker running, and not the libcontainer version.

How do I explicitly replace this lxe-docker 1.5 with libcontainer docker 1.5?

Comment: Unrelated to programming, please go to AskUbuntu, ServerFault or SuperUser and ask there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the name of the package. The name docker was already being used by another package in Ubuntu, so Docker decided to call this one lxc-docker. It became a bit unfortunate when Docker moved to libcontainer.

To check which execution driver you're using, run `docker info`:

```
$ docker info
...
Execution Driver: native-0.2
...
```

If you see "native" here, you're using libcontainer.